# Transformation of extrinsic camera parameters from solvePnP

Tags: java, kotlin, opencv, camera-calibration, opencv-solvepnp

I have a camera that has known intrinsic parameters but unknown extrinsic parameters. I am attempting to get an extrinsic calibration and to do that, I positioned a chessboard pattern with known world coordinates in the frame of the camera. To get the extrinsic calibration, I am comparing two OpenCV methods from the Calib3D module:

```
val flags = CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS or
    CALIB_FIX_PRINCIPAL_POINT or
    CALIB_FIX_FOCAL_LENGTH or
    CALIB_FIX_K1 or
    CALIB_FIX_K2 or
    CALIB_FIX_K3 or
    CALIB_FIX_K4 or
    CALIB_FIX_K5 or
    CALIB_FIX_K6 or
    CALIB_FIX_S1_S2_S3_S4 or
    CALIB_FIX_TAUX_TAUY
val overallRms = Calib3d.calibrateCamera(
    objectPoints,
    imagePoints,
    imageSize,
    cameraMatrix,
    distortionCoefficients,
    rotationVectors,
    translationVectors,
    flags
)
```

and

```
val solveReturnValue = Calib3d.solvePnP(
    objectPointsInFrame.second,
    imagePointsInFrame.second,
    cameraMatrix,
    distortionCoefficients,
    rotationVector,
    translationVector,
    false // useExtrinsicsGuess
)
```

Both methods yield the same results for translation and rotation +- 1.5 units. However, I have read on multiple occasions (e.g., [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/133855/does-anyone-actually-use-the-return-values-of-solvepnp-to-compute-the-coordinates-of-the-camera-wrt-the-object-in-the-world-space/) ) that `solvePnP` yields the inverse of `calibrateCamera` and one needs to invert the transformation again by

1. computing the rotation matrix `R` from the rotation vector using `Calib3D.Rodrigues()`
2. inverting the rotation by inverting the rotation matrix
3. inverting the translation using `-R.t()*tvec`

which according to my testing does not seem to be the case. Hence, my questions: Is it safe to assume that  `rotationVectors` and `translationVectors` are the extrinsic calibration of the camera? And when is the aforementioned transformation actually necessary?

Comment: According to my own tests from some years ago, solvePnp gives the object pose, so to get the camera extrinsics you would have to invert. BUT maybe opencv changed the behaviour in a later version. If you place the camera front-facing to the chessboard (rotation nearly 0, x and y nearly 0), what's the z position coordinate given in solvePnp? Is it positive or negative? If you move the cam to some x coordinate, does this fit to your chessboard-coordinate-system or to its inverse?

Comment: Have a look at the docs, even for calibrateCamera it says fit rvec/tvec: "this tuple is equivalent to the position of the calibration pattern with respect to the camera coordinate space." So imho if you are searching the camera pose in the board-coordinate-system you have to invert rvec and tvec. Still,if possible, you should verify this in a controlled setup where the camera extrinsics are coarsely known. Thus can also help to understand the actual coordinate systems.